# Getting value of a variable the moment the function is declared?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Let's say I declare a function and use it as a handler for an event on an object.

Let's say that it needs to access a variable who's value will change before the event is called.

How do I provide to the function the value of the variable the moment the function is declared?

For example:

```
var I_Like_to_Change_Frequently = "...";

some_DOM_object.addEventListener( "some_arbitrary_event_to_fire_later", function I_Need_the_Current_Value(){

  alert( "at the time I was defined, 'I_Like_to_Change_Frequently' was " + I_Like_to_Change_Frequently)

})

var I_Like_to_Change_Frequently = undefined //doesn't really matter. The point is it changes
```

**EDIT:** This codeblock is repeated multiple times in a for loop where some_DOM_object is different each iteration. Every iteration I_Like_to_Change_Frequently changes as well.

Comment: A trivial solution is to store the current value in a second variable right before setting the event handler.

Comment: @ChrisG I just thought of that just now, updated question

Comment: using `new Function()` could work, but I don't think it is ideal

Comment: Just do this: `some_DOM_object.myData = I_Like_To...;`

Comment: @ChrisG I tried that once, but it broke my code. Let me try it again to see if it works.

Comment: You need of course be careful not to overwrite some existing property. The answer you got is a better solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple options:

1) Move your code into a function. The function parameter will be a new binding, and thus will be "locked in" to that value

```
function createListener(domObject, val) {
   domObject.addEventListener("some_arbitrary_event_to_fire_later", function () {
      alert("at the time i was defined, I_Like_to_Change_Frequently was " + val;
   });
}

var I_Like_to_Change_Frequently = "...";

createListener(some_DOM_object, I_Like_to_Change_Frequently);

var I_Like_to_Change_Frequently = undefined
```

2) Do it inline with an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
var I_Like_to_Change_Frequently = "...";

(function (val) {
   some_DOM_object.addEventListener( "some_arbitrary_event_to_fire_later", 
      function (){
         alert( "at the time I was defined, 'I_Like_to_Change_Frequently' was " + val)
      })
})(I_Like_to_Change_Frequently);

var I_Like_to_Change_Frequently = undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `Function.prototype.bind()`:

You can also make use of the javascript `bind()` function to define the scope of the function.

This way, the variable value at the time of creation of the function can be retained.

```
some_DOM_object.addEventListener( "some_arbitrary_event_to_fire_later", (function I_Need_the_Current_Value(){

  alert( "at the time I was defined, 'I_Like_to_Change_Frequently' was " + this.variableAtTheTimeOfCreation)

}).bind({variableAtTheTimeOfCreation: I_Like_to_Change_Frequently}));
```

#### Breakdown:

In this example, we bind the function to a scope object `{variableAtTheTimeOfCreation: I_Like_to_Change_Frequently}`.

When the handler executes, it's `this` will be the scope object we defined and bound to it (**which was at creation**).

**[More on `Function.prototype.bind()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**